# Не срабатывает метод JLabel.setText(String text)

Tags: java, jframe

Реализовал "делегат" на java используя метод в интерфейсе с сигнатурой void(string). При попытке вызова таким образом метода JLabel.setText(String text) программа падает, однако, если закинуть другой метод (месаджбокс/ вывод в консоль) все исправно работает.

Компилятор ошибок не выдает, окно программы "замораживается".

Игра типа "змейка", вывод игрового поля посредством JLable. Код:

Имеется класс "Формы". Это GUI. Здесь мы создаем экземпляр класса "движок", закидываем ему ссылку на метод setText и выводим карту в JLable:

```
public class Form extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JLabel _gameLablel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Form().setVisible(true);
}

private Form() {
    super("My Game");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    _gameLablel = new JLabel("sample text");
    _gameLablel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    _gameLablel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            StartGame();
        }
    });
    add(_gameLablel);
}

private void StartGame() {
    EingeClass ec = new EingeClass(new IDelegate() {
        @Override
        public void AnMethod(String s) {
            _gameLablel.setText(s);
        }
    });
    ec.StartShowing();
}}
```

Имеется класс "Игровой движок", запускающий генерацию карты и вызов ее отрисовки с заданной частотой:

```
class EingeClass {
Map m;
IDelegate del;

public EingeClass(IDelegate d) {
    this.m = new Map();
    this.del = d;
}

public void StartShowing() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            del.AnMethod(m.ShowMap());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

И самопальный "делегат" для передачи ссылки на метод отрисовки:

```
interface IDelegate {
void AnMethod(String s);}
```

Класс "карты" отвечает за генерацию карты и возвращает строку с картой:

```
class Map {
char[][] _mapField = new char[10][10];
char _wall = '#';
char _grass = '+';

public Map() {
    GenerateMap();
}

void GenerateMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _mapField[0].length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < _mapField[1].length; j++)
            if ((i > 0 && j > 0) && (i < _mapField[0].length - 1 && j < _mapField[1].length - 1))
                _mapField[i][j] = _grass;
            else
                _mapField[i][j] = _wall;
}

String ShowMap() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < _mapField[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _mapField[1].length; j++)
            s += _mapField[i][j];
        s += System.lineSeparator();
    }
    return s;
}}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки был бы очень кстати

Comment: Добавил инфу об ошибке в пост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перерисовка графики происходит после завершения обработчика событий

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
   StartGame();
}
```

А ваш код уходит в бесконечный цикл внутри обработчика, поэтому интерфейс никогда не перерисовывается.